# Gift authorships and necessary actions

Tags: research-process, authorship, research-misconduct

In my paper as well as in others there is a specific person that acquired gift authorships. How do I speak about that anonymously? Should I send an anonynous email to integrity office? or to the journal? I don't know how to handle the situation and I need some guidance. Apparently something is going on with this person. Is it possible a person to be handed authorship on papers across departments without significant contribution (eg. helped with 2 constructs, set up a PCR, helped with an experiment aliquoting sample supernatants, etc.) and this to be done for non-suspicious reasons?

Comment: What you describe actually sounds like a contribution. "Significant" can be a judgement call. People can be generous with that call without it becoming "gift" authorship.

Comment: in one paper this äuthor" contributed to a panel (supplement) along with other 4 authors - just or one experiment. In the same paper another person contributing a panel was put in the acknowledgements.

Comment: This language in this one is hard for me to understand. You could talk to your University ombud non-anonymously for guidance.

Comment: Given that in your previous question you were hoping to get someone's Ph.D. revoked on the grounds that their thesis is not strong enough (indicating a seriously skewed perspective on what is a significant enough issue to result in the revocation of one's Ph.D.), perhaps you should allow for the possibility that your perspective on what counts as a significant enough contribution to a paper may also be skewed compared to the rest of academia.

Answer (score 4):

The amount of contribution is a fickle matter. Students tend to view it as very black-and-white and are overly protective of their work (and tend to deem others' contributions as insignificant), while those with more experience managing research groups - and, admittedly, valuing evidence of them being good at managing the team higher - are more likely to include a lot of authors.

Nominally, you are very likely to have at least some case here: one of the checkboxes one gets to fill when sending a paper to a journal is a confirmation that all authors agree to a publication and listings of others' respective contributions, especially if something like [CRediT](https://credit.niso.org/) is being used. But anonymity is likely not an option in your case. How likely is that someone not familiar with their work flags them as dishonest? How many people are in the authors' list of their recent papers? How long would it take for them to talk to each other and figure out who was the most likely person to yell "misconduct!"?

The reality of a situation is that the practice of gift authorship in this case (which does not even seem completely outrageous to me, try people just exchanging money under the table!) may be so deeply rooted you could not possibly hope to bring it down, especially not without causing a very considerable harm to yourself. You surely could demand a stricter standards of contribution on papers where you are one of key authors, but that is about it. If you come across something unmistakably egregious, you could report it to someone in the university like Thomas Schwarz said (and be prepared for them potentially sweeping the issue under the rug to not deal with the fallout; the only viable escalation from there is burning the house down by getting press involved).

It is very, very hard to argue your case there, unless some *extremely* apparent corruption was involved. Authors get to collectively decide whose contributions were significant and whose were not; if you stir up trouble, not working with you would be an easier option for the rest of them, and it may well end up being a career suicide for you. Until your own contributions are valuable enough for others to play by your rules, you get to play by theirs or look for a more perceivably ethically sound team to be in, sorry. Not a lot of leverage there.

Comment: are you trying to scare me that i will have retaliation? I already had but for another miscompetent individual who happened to be assigned as my daily supervisor. What could be extremely apparent corruption according to you? I am also not working with them so no problem. This goes across teams and does not involve only one team.

Comment: @oknow No, I am just stating that 1) It is unlikely you would achieve a good semblance of anonymity while reporting misconduct in this case, as it was explicitly requested and 2) If all you want is to report something, no problem. If you are actually interested in it effecting some change, you have to have some leverage.

Comment: If your apparently high standards are to become the norm, it should be demonstrable that they are usable and, in fact, superior. Lead by example. Show others how you *still* publish papers and get funding without engaging in dubious practices such as disputable authorships; supervise a few students invariably producing high-quality theses. This may put you at a perceived disadvantage, but good ethics is well worth it. I am a perfectionist, too, but either I can show how my way is better, or I am wrong and have to tone it down because these suggestions won't work for other people.

Answer (score 3):

A useful answer would require much more knowledge about your situation, which you probably should not provide. As a co-author, you should know who was responsible for this person to be included as an author and why this authorship is not warranted. Also, how can you be sure that these are gift authorships on the other papers?

At a US institution, you could bring your concerns (not accusations) to a Dean or a VP for research.

Comment: Of course the last author.

Comment: Still, people were answering my questions, none got in the paper though.  In general I have used protocols of others and others of mine and I was not in their publications and they were not in mine. So I learned that sharing expertise unless it is very special, novel etc is normal between colleagues

Comment: otherwise all publications would have 100 authors or - god forbid - we would do everyything by ourselves reinventing the weel every time. Or design RT-PCR ( but not performing it?) in author contribution. At least the could just write just investigation and manuscript revision. Also setting up an RT PCR is controversial regarding if it guarantees authorship.  For european university?

Comment: this goes ater my first comment. Either I learned it wrong so that I would be taken advantage of or helping with cloning is suicient to get you in the authors list. I have designed construct for inducible knockout and got really helped by lots o my colleagues.

Comment: In my case this person made me start to wonder whether talking to someone in everyday fashion and receiving some input and encouragement should make me put their names in my publication otherwse I am a really bad person not collaborative and not appreciative enough. !!!!!! I also received some messages mildly blackmailing stating  how my PI likes this person!!!!! He also helped me once with a presentation and the rehearsal. Omg I should have put many on my other publications then. Really weird with this guy what does he do! no grants,  no first author publications for him! Like...how?

Comment: @oknow You seem to be reacting very emotionally to this situation. In almost any professional setting it makes it nightmarishly difficult to argue your point. Also, your paper, your call, but if people felt their contributions were significant enough and you left them out, it could put you in trouble. And yes, in HEP publications very commonly have hundreds of authors, many of them students doing a meager amount of work in the grand scheme of things. In my field, if a person has worked in the lab on samples at least for a bit, they are likely to get authorship.